# RecyclerView inside CoordinatorLayout scrolls before Toolbar is colapsed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an image and a recyclerview, and I would like it to scroll as if they were inside a NestedScrollView. But I also want my RecyclerView to recycle the views (not to load everything like in a listview).

To achieve that, I am using a CoordinatorLayout. But it's not working the way that I need.
The RecyclerView is scrolling even when the CollapsibleToolbar is not collapsed.

Could anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? I have tried everything I read here on StackOverflow, nothing worked.

I already tried android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" and "false" as suggested in similar questions. Didn't work.

androidx version: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".ToVisitFragment"
android:id="@+id/to_visit_container">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/to_visit_coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/to_visit_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/to_visit_collapsing_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/to_visit_map"
                    style="@style/WorldMap"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/world_map"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/to_visit_regions_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_region" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/to_visit_button_add"
    style="@style/MyFloatingActionButton"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_add_city"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/purple"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT**

After @BenjyTec mentioned the recyclerView item layout file, I found the problem. I have another recyclerView inside the item. I had set isScrollContainer to false, but didn't set nestedScrollView to false on the inner recyclerView.

Here is the working code:

item layout:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/region_title"
        style="@style/Title"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="América Latina"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/region_country_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/region_title"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_country"/>
```

Coordinator Layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/to_visit_coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/to_visit_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/to_visit_collapsing_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/to_visit_map"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/map_world"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/grey_200"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/world_map"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:11"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/to_visit_regions_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_region"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/to_visit_button_add"
        style="@style/MyFloatingActionButton"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_add_city"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/purple"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a small sample app to test out the combination of `RecyclerView` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The result I get from the sample app looks like this:

[image: Screenrecording]

Is that what you want to achieve? If yes, and it still does not work, you might want to show your layout file of the `RecyclerView` items, as the culprit might be there.

Also, your root `ConstraintLayout` might be useless. If you only need it to place the FloatingActionButton, you can also achieve the same thing by using CoordinatorLayout attribute `layout_gravity`, as shown below.

Below is the layout for the sample app:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/to_visit_coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/to_visit_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/to_visit_collapsing_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/to_visit_map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/photo"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/to_visit_regions_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/to_visit_button_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="Description"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the layout file for the RecyclerView items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAnimalName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but adding the Toolbar didn't change anything. The behavior I want is the normal scrolling... to move the image out of the screen at the same time that the recyclerview is moving top, and only after the recyclerview reaches the top it would start to scroll its items... but it is scrolling the items underneath the AppBar before it's collapsed... (sorry if it's confusing, my english is not the best...)

Comment: I think I understand. I rewrote my answer. Is that what you are aiming for?

Comment: You saved my day! That's the behavior that I want. After you mentioned the recyclerview items, I found the problem... I have a recycler view inside the item with isScrollContainer="false", but I didn't set nestedScrollingEnabled="false". Now it's working.

Comment: Hey @BenjyTec Do you have any idea how can I solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72609914/11560810)