# Searchview in centre and after focus it goes to app bar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

Hey guys I am learning Searchview in android. I have searchview in centre and when I focus it will go to app bar just like chrome application.

[image]

And when focus it will go to app bar

[image]

I didn't find any solution. Can someone guide me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I remember a good tutorial regarding transition animation: I think [this one](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-motion-android#4)

Basically, I'd would need 2 Activities(Fragments) and both have SearchView. When user click on SearchView you would you transition animation to make an affect of moving SearchView from first screen to the second

Comment: Seems to be a valid idea. Maybe you don't need the SearchView on the first screen as it acts more like button that triggers the transition and shows the second fragment.